# Site hosted in Azure registered through Go Daddy having security and certificate issues

Tags: azure, ssl

I've have a domain registered with Go Daddy that I have routed back to Azure by updating the C Name and A records in Go Daddy to point to my Azure site. And, I have updated my webconfig file with the information below.  I can navigate to the site, but I'm getting a bunch of certificate and security errors when browsing to it, stating the site is potentially unsafe. Has anyone run into this before and if so, is there something I'm missing in the web config file or a cert issue I need to configure in Go Daddy and/or Azure?  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect old-domain to new-domain" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^lazyquiz.azurewebsites.net$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.lazyquiz.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\." />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="localhost" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: have you uploaded your certificate to your Azure website?

Comment: @JuneT No, I have not.  Are the instructions located in this article, https://support2.microsoft.com/common/survey.aspx?scid=sw;en;3864&showpage=1 a good starting point?

Comment: yes, its in that article... Configure SSL